# Jquery + Selectivizer to reproduce nth-child in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors, selectivizr

My understanding from selectivizr is that it can interpret a number of pseudo-classes correctly in ie6-8.  I've been having trouble with what I want to accomplish, no matter what I try, it runs perfectly in Chrome/Firefox but falls flat on its face in IE6.  Any help would be awesome!

CSS

```
#menu li img
{
    position: absolute;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
}

#menu li:nth-child(odd) img
{
    top: 0px;
}

#menu li:nth-child(even) img
{
    bottom: 0px;
}

#menu li span
{
    position: absolute;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    padding: 5px;
}

#menu li:nth-child(odd) span
{
    top: 150px;
}

#menu li:nth-child(even) span
{
    bottom: 150px;
}
```

Jquery/Selectivizer:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
<script language="JavaScript" src="selectivizr-min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

HTML

```
<li><img src="menu/menu01-01.jpg" /><span>過橋米線 NT.100</span></li><li>
<img src="menu/menu01-02.jpg" /><span>昆明辣泡菜鍋米干/米線 NT.100</span></li><li>
<img src="menu/menu01-03.jpg" /><span>阿美米干/米線 NT.80</span></li><li>
<img src="menu/menu01-04.jpg" /><span>雲燒牛腩米干/米線 NT.100</span></li><li>
<img src="menu/menu01-05.jpg" /><span>豆腐乳/臘肉炒飯 NT.80</span></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you put all your css in a link rel?  Selectivizr will not work with css in style blocks.  I simplified and this works, proving that even and odd work alone in selectivizr.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="selectivizr.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><span>過橋米線 NT.100</span></li>
        <li><span>昆明辣泡菜鍋米干/米線 NT.100</span></li>
        <li><span>阿美米干/米線 NT.80</span></li>
        <li><span>雲燒牛腩米干/米線 NT.100</span></li>
        <li><span>豆腐乳/臘肉炒飯 NT.80</span></li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="selectivizr.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```